# How To Configure OpenSSH on a Windows Server 2008 to authenticate against Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, ssh, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed OpenSSH 7.1 on a Windows server 2008R2 which also is an Active Directory Domain Controller. I need to login with SSH on this machine using credentials from Active Directory e.g., using domain user credentials.

How do I configure OpenSSH on a Windows 2008R2 server to allow this?

Currently, if I try to login with a domain user I get a `permission denied` error.